# Is there a package.json "files" equivalent in composer.json?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm looking to send a composer package to our groups internal [gitlab registry](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/composer_repository/) using a custom CD pipeline task.

My issue is that I only want to publish my `dist` directory to the registry and was hoping I could do something like the ["files" property in package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#files).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the [composer.json schema](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md) shows anything like it.

I'd suggest to have a CI pipeline building and commiting a dist-only version on a release branch, then tag the generated commit for release.